# How to fit tall image at the screen's height (Twitter Bootstrap 3)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Simple situation but wasn't able to find workable solution.

I have a column. Let's say **.col-sm-6.** 
 - 1. I put tall (!) image in it. And make it responsive. 
 - 2. I also put text block at second column.

I want my image will be fit to the screen height without scrolling. 
How can I make it?

```
<div class="container">
```

```
 <div class="col-md-6" >

   <img src='http://goo.gl/jqY6bj' class="img-responsive"/></img>

 </div>

    <div class="col-md-6" >

  <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>

 </div>
```

As you can see here: http://www.bootply.com/T82DuMTTWU my picture has it's default dimensions.

Comment: Bootstrap won't help you there. Look up ```max-height```

Comment: You could make it a background image so that it completely fills the div regardless of orientation...

Comment: Nathanchill,  do I need to write new classes for max-height for every screen height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the img-responsive class in bootstrap take 100% of the parent block width and set height to auto. You have to do the opposite and you can create your own class for height responsive.

```
.height-responsive {
    width: auto;
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Salmen, look please http://www.bootply.com/YB5rxzMCtL#. It doesn't work for my example.

Comment: If you want your block to fit to the screen height, all the parents should fit also the screen height putting height: 100%;